# reloadData changed Delegate and dataSource into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a problem when I try populate a **UITableView** from web service data.

I have this methods.

```
#pragma UITableView methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSLog(@"count... %i-%@-%@",[self.tweets count], _myTable.delegate, _myTable.dataSource);
return [self.tweets count];
 }

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 95;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"Cell...");
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TweetCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }


if ([self.tweets count] != 0) {
    SBTVTweets *current_tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.username.text = current_tweet.name;
}

return cell;
}


//Clicked Row in the Table View action
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"Clicked");
}
```

And in this method I called the method **reloadData**

```
-(Table *)initWithTweets:(NSArray *)tweets{
      self = [self init];
      if (self) {
        self.tweets = [tweets copy];
     }
    [self.myTable reloadData];
    return self;
}
```

This is the **IBOutlet** of my *table*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
```

In my file **.h** I have this.

```
@interface Table : UIView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

When executed that, the log show me:

```
 2014-10-20 12:52:37.026 NuncheeTestsApp[15717:110695] count... 0-<Table: 0x7c198e50; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c19a200>>-<Table: 0x7c198e50; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c19a200>>
 2014-10-20 12:52:37.033 NuncheeTestsApp[15717:110695] count... 0-<Table: 0x7c198e50; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c19a200>>-<Table: 0x7c198e50; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c19a200>>
 2014-10-20 12:52:39.518 NuncheeTestsApp[15717:110695] count... 20-<Table: 0x7c1a7ba0; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c1949c0>>-<Table: 0x7c1a7ba0; frame = (0 0; 524 265); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c1949c0>
```

In the third time the array is populated but the **delegate** and **dataSource** changed and the **UITableVIew** doesn't show anything. I have no idea...

Any Idea.

Thanks.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, what does po self.tweets tell you?

Comment: In the last time, when the array is populate `(count... 20)` this method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't execute.

Comment: You're obviously creating a new Table object the third time around.  I'm guessing you used `[[Table alloc] initWithTweets:...]` to set the tweets array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd say don't call `reloadData` from your initializer. You're better off calling that in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myTable reloadData];
}
```

Secondly, I can't from what you've posted if you're using a `UITableViewController` or just a `UIViewController`. If it's the latter, you'll need to set your **delegate** and **datasource** yourself:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTable.delegate = self;
    self.myTable.dataSource = self;

    [self.myTable reloadData];
}
```

Also, since a couple of versions ago you can use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which takes care of the **nil** case for you:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTable.delegate = self;
    self.myTable.dataSource = self;

    [self.myTable registerClass:[TweetCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    [self.myTable reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.tweets count] != 0) {
        SBTVTweets *current_tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.username.text = current_tweet.name;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

**EDIT**

I just realized you're subclassing `UIView` for all this code. As I mentioned above, probably easiest to subclass `UITableViewController` instead, which already conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. It also adds the `UITableView` for you.

Comment: Thanks... But this Table Class is a **UIView**. I try this but I get the seem error... The table doesn't show anything...

Comment: Yeah you probably shouldn't have the view being a datasource (or delegate) really.